# How to show the maximum number of data into swt combobox?

Tags: java, combobox, resize, swt, dropdown

My SWT Combo has a lot of items and the dropdownlist always shows more data at the same time in linux platform based on display size. (yes I can scroll up and down to see all the other items)

I want the dropdown list to show items at the same time e.g. 10 items at the same time.

I used this code:

```java
m_comboBoxViewer.getCCombo().setVisibleItemCount(10);
```

I am getting this exception:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ComboViewer.getCCombo(ComboViewer.java:182)
```

How can I make the dropdown list, to show limited items at the same time? Has anyone an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a `ComboViewer` which is using a `Combo` control. You must use a `CCombo` control to be able to set the visible items count.

```java
CCombo comboBox = new CCombo(parent, ... style flags ....);
m_comboBoxViewer = new ComboViewer(comboBox);
```